# How to delete *.tfstate file from backend S3 bucket

Tags: terraform

I have backend on aws s3 bucket, where I have all my ***.tfstate** files.
When I do

```
cd terraform/project.foo
terraform destroy
```

I would like that it will also remove **foo.tfstate** file from my backend S3 Bucket, but it's not doing so.

Is there any option, to remove needed tfstate file from backend via terraform?

Thank you!

Comment: your tfstate file consists the info on what action is performed and the status of the resources you are configuring using terraform. Terraform will not delete this file. It doesn't really harm to have that tfstate file and is recommended to have it.

Comment: you can do that with the AWS cli something like `aws s3 rm s3://mybucket/foo.tfstate`  https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/reference/s3/rm.html

Comment: Thank you!
@VamshiSiddarth, I would like to do this, because each branch is creating new *.tfstate file, and it's kind a polluting the S3 Bucket, and I wont use them after merge to master.

Comment: @HelderSepulveda it's an option, will try to use it in GitHub Actions.
Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

This is totally possible if you are using **[Terraform workspace](https://www.terraform.io/docs/state/workspaces.html)**

I had two workspace default and prod.

I switched to prod workspace and ran terraform destroy

[image: prod workspace - terrafrom destroy command]

This is the S3 state file content, post `terraform destroy`
[image: terraform destroy - state file]

Once destroyed, switch to default workspace `terraform workspace select default`

From default workspace run `terraform workspace delete prod`

[image: terraform workspace destroy]

Poof, your state file is completely cleared up

[image: post-delete s3 file]

**Note:** I'm using fish shell with Terraform plugin, terraform workspace gets printed in prompt (represented by arrow )